# Getting an "Aggregate" at a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, where-clause, having, having-clause

1029/5000
I have 2 tables which are linked by the serial number (DeviceID).
Table 1 (C) lists all downloaded cyclist data.
Table 2 (T) lists the data about the device and when the last download took place.

Now I want to do a group by with the average speed of the last 3 6 or 12 months (counted from today).
This goes without problems.
However, when I get the average speed of the last 3 6 or 12 months **counted from the last download** I am going to get:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Code 1 that goes OK:

```sql
SELECT  
    C.DeviceID
    , AVG(C.Speed) AS AVG_Speed
    , DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.LogDateTime, GETDATE()) AS Months
FROM Compass C
JOIN Transfer T ON C.DeviceID = T.DeviceID
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.LogDateTime, GETDATE()) <= @EvalTimeFrame
GROUP BY C.DeviceID
```

Code 2 that goes wrong:

```sql
SELECT  
    C.DeviceID
    , AVG(C.Speed) AS AVG_Speed
    , DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.LogDateTime, GETDATE())) - (DATEDIFF(MONTH, MAX(T.TransferDateTime), GETDATE()) AS Months
FROM Compass C
JOIN Transfer T ON C.DeviceID = T.DeviceID
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.LogDateTime, GETDATE())) - (DATEDIFF(MONTH, MAX(T.TransferDateTime), GETDATE())) <= @EvalTimeFrame
GROUP BY C.DeviceID
```

Acually what I want to have is:

---

GROUP BY C.DeviceID,  (DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.LogDateTime, GETDATE())) - (DATEDIFF(MONTH, MAX(T.TransferDateTime), GETDATE()))

---

It would help me a lot - any idea?

Comment: first, you're trying to return `C.LogDateTime` column in the select but it's not included in `group by` clause. How Sql Server supposed to choose which value to return? I have some doubts that your first query actually works.
May be to make it easier you can create a working example on dbfiddle.co.uk or sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Try wrapping your DATEDIFF expression in MIN() or MAX(), or remove it altogether from the SELECT.

Comment: MAX() does not work because I use it is a loop where the @EvalTimeFrame each time changes. (3,6,12)